# How do you configure Gitlab CI dockers to test different requirements (Language env, database, etc.)?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am creating an API that uses Python, Mongo, and Redis and I wanted to use Gitlab CI.

Do I have to build a Dockerfile with all these requirements? Or is there a way to just write some instructions in the .gitlab-ci.yml and call the different images in Dockerhub?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should. Although this is not a Gitlab specific question (and thus answer) it is considered a best-practice to separate tasks and functions (in Docker terms; One concern per container). I don't want to call it a micro-service approach but you should consider splitting all processes.

Some fundamental concepts to help you:

- [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) (Splitting [processes](https://12factor.net/processes))
- [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) ([One concern](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#avoid-installing-unnecessary-packages))

Since you mention Python and API I suppose your application is writen in Python and you use MongoDB and Redis as persistent data stores?

Take a look at the official Docker images and how to use them, this should make your life splitting concerns a lot easier:

- [MongoDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)
- [Redis](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/)

There is also an [official Python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) to help you on your way. Just add your app code and get going!

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can write in a **.gitlab-ci.yml** a tag:

`- services:
   - redis:4.0.2
   - mongo:3.4.10`

Which uses other **services** that are on Dockerhub.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-to-use-other-images-as-services